# How to insert menu at left column in magento using diffrent theme

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I install theme and made my home page of three columns, I have a menu on top of products and category.I want that menu on my left hand side in page . 
i
found the 
 `3cloumn.phtml`
 here
 `D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page` 
i copy that file in my theme here 
`D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\bluescale\template\page\html`
but i am doing any changes in my theme on that page is not reflecting at front end . And how i can put that top product related menu on left hand side.

Comment: have you needed home page or product list page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in default/bluescale/layout/page.xml, before this `</layout>`:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.leftnav" template="page/html/leftmenu.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Of course, you have to set the right block data (type, name and template). You can find it from your page.xml.

Clean the cache.

Or, you can install this module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html.

Comment: i put that code but its not working , I think I am not understanding it , I am new in magento

Comment: i want like this [http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Rico+Neitzel/extension/763/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes]